# The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information

Tags: c#, xna

One of my projects in my visual studios has become unstable. It appears to have unloaded itself, the name is now "Shared (load failed)" instead of the original name "Shared".

It is telling me "The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information." as a message within the project.

When I try to reload the project I get this message. [image]

I have not changed anything in my project, I cannot think of why this has happened.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. I had a Windows update this morning that caused something to go wrong with my Visual Studio 2015. I ran the installer and repaired my Visual Studios followed by a restart of my computer to fix this error.